# Prove that prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log(1 + \frac{x}{n})}{n}$ is not uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{R}$ by contradiction

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, uniform-convergence

I want to prove that $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log(1 + \frac{x}{n})}{n}$ is not uniformly convergent on the whole of $\mathbb{R}$.

My idea was to make the argument that if $f(x)$ were uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{R}$, then $\exists N\in\mathbb{N} $ such that  $|f(x) - f_n(x)|<\epsilon $ for any $\epsilon > 0$ and any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ when $N\leq n$. 
Let $f(x)-f_n(x) = \sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty}\frac{\log(1 + \frac{x}{k})}{k}$. Choose $\epsilon = 1$ and $x = k\cdot e^k$. Then, $\left|\sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty}\frac{\log(1 + \frac{x}{k})}{k}\right|= \left|\sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty}\frac{\log\left(1 + \frac{k\cdot e^k}{k}\right)}{k}\right| > 1$, which contradicts the proposition that we can make $\bigl|f(x) - f_n(x)\bigr|$ smaller than any epsilon by choosing $N$ large enough.

Somehow this argument feels faulty. Can I really choose $x$ in such an arbitrary way? $k$ is after all not a constant, but $x$ might need to be?

Any insights into this would be appreciated.

Comment: How is the series defined when $x\leqslant-1$?

Comment: Good point. I assume they are asking for $x\in\mathbb{R}, x \leq 0$ but forgot to include the detail.

Comment: "$x\le0$" meaning $x\geqslant0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea. Here is another way to use the same idea.

Let $f_n(x)=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac {\log (1+x/j)}{j}$ for $x>-1$ (...so $\log (1+x/j)$ is defined when $j=1$).

Let $f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x).$

Let $\|f-f_n\|=\sup_{x>-1}|f(x)-f_n(x)|.$

Then directly from the definition, $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$  on $(-1,\infty)$ iff $\lim_{n\to \infty}\|f-f_n\|=0.$

For $m>1$ let $x_m=m(e^m-1).$ We have $f_m(x_m) -f_{m-1}(x_m)=1.$

For any $n$  we have $$\|f_{n+1}-f\|+\|f-f_n\|\geq$$  $$\geq |f_{n+1}(x_{n+1})-f(x_{n+1})|+|f(x_{n+1})-f_n(x_{n+1})|\geq$$ $$\geq |f_{n+1}(x_{n+1})-f(x_{n+1})+f(x_{n+1})-f_n(x_{n+1})|=$$    $$=|f_{n+1}(x_{n+1})-f_n(x_{n+1})|=1.$$

Therefore $\max (\|f_{n+1}-f\|, \|f-f_n\|)\geq 1/2.$

So for every $n$ there exists $n'\geq n$ (...namely $n'=n$ or $n'=n+1$) such that $\|f-f_{n'}\|\geq 1/2.$ Therefore $\|f-f_n\|$ does not converge to $0$ as $n\to \infty.$

Comment: If a real sequence $(r_n)_n$ converges  it is necessary that $|r_{n+1}-r_n|$ converges to $0.$ Similarly if a sequence $(f_n)_n$ of functions converges uniformly  it is necessary that $\|f_{n+1}-f_n\|$ converges to $0.$ But $\|f_{n+1}-f_n\|\geq |f_{n+1}(x_{n+1})-f_n(x_{n+1})|=1.$

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the infinite series is not well-defined for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$
and $n$ should not start at $n=0$ (otherwise, zero will appear in
the denominator). If we let $x$ take negative value, $\ln(1+\frac{x}{n})$
may be un-defined.

Let me correct the question to: Prove that the infinite series 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(1+\frac{x}{n})}{n}
$$
 converges pointwisely but not uniformly on $[0,\infty)$.

Proof: We firstly prove that the infinite series converges pointwisely
for each $x\in[0,\infty)$. Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$ be fixed. Note that
$\frac{\ln(1+\frac{x}{n})}{n}\geq0$ and 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(1+\frac{x}{n})}{n}\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{n^{2}}<\infty.
$$
Here, we have used the fact $\ln(1+x)\leq x$ for all $x\in[0,\infty)$.
By comparison test, the infinite series converges. Denote $S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(1+\frac{x}{n})}{n}$.

/////////////////////////////////////////

Next, we show that the infinite series does not coverge uniformly
to $S(x)$ on $[0,\infty)$. Denote the partial sum by $S_{n}(x)$.
That is, $S_{n}(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\ln(1+\frac{x}{k})}{k}$. Prove
by contradiction. Suppose the contrary that $S_{n}\rightarrow S$
uniformly on $[0,\infty)$. Then for $\epsilon=0.1$, there exists
$N$ such that $\sup_{x\in[0,\infty)}|S_{m}(x)-S_{n}(x)|<\epsilon$
whenever $m,n\geq N$. Observe that $\frac{\ln(1+\frac{x}{N+1})}{N+1}\rightarrow\infty$
as $x\rightarrow\infty$, so there exists $x_{0}\in[0,\infty)$ such
that $\frac{\ln(1+\frac{x_{0}}{N+1})}{N+1}>1$. Finally, observe that
$$
1<\frac{\ln(1+\frac{x_{0}}{N+1})}{N+1}=\left|S_{N+1}(x_{0})-S_{N}(x_{0})\right|\leq\sup_{x\in[0,\infty)}|S_{N+1}(x)-S_{N}(x)|<\epsilon,
$$
which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Useful general result: If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)$ converges uniformly on a set $E,$ then $\sup_{E} |f_n| \to 0$ as $n\to \infty.$ In your problem, take $E=[0,\infty),$ $f_n(x) = (\ln (1+x/n))/n.$ Then $\sup_{E} |f_n| =\infty$ for each $n.$ Thus uniform convergence in your problem fails, bigtime.

Comment: Note that the converse isn't true in general.  But there is a partial converse which is often useful: if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sup_E |f_n|$ converges (and if the target is complete), then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ converges uniformly on $E$.